# How to fix Django website showing 404 errors on all website links online

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, cpanel, production-environment

so i recently uploaded a my first django website on cpanel . After uploading i realised the website is showing 404 errors on all website links ... let me show the links and urls

```
`from .views.home import Index , shop, about


urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('store', shop, name='store'),
    path('about-us', about , name='about-us'),
]
`
```

The design of the website is supposed to automatically go to example.com/shop as the main page but its showing 404 errors instead

so **.views** is a folder under **shop** app

Need assistance on urls and how to correctly configure my website to show content after page load

Answer (score 0):

You might not have included the shops app in you main url.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('' , include('shop.urls')),      ...... i have these links in the main django project  but am still getting 404 errors on all website links

Comment: Your base URL "127.0.0.1:8000" is redirecting to which page?

Comment: its redirecting to 127.0.0.1:8000/shop

Comment: and my static configurations in settings.py llok like                  STATIC_URL = 'static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/cpanel_username/domain_name/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static/", 
]